# How do you rollback an entire chain job based on failed step

Tags: oracle

I have a chain job of 40 steps that was recently converted over from a scheduled job. When a part of the scheduled job failed, the entire transaction would rollback.

From my understanding, each step of the train is its own transaction, when something fails, only the step that failed gets rolled back.

I could have the first step of the chain create a restore point and have a step waiting for a failure to rollback, but this seems like too much work. Is there a better way? Some chain definition that I dont know of?

In case it matters, this will be for an Oracle 12 environment, but testing is being done in an Oracle 11 environment.

Comment: Surely the advantage of restructuring one monolithic procedure into 40 steps is that you gain some control over which parts to restart on failure.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson It wasnt one monolithic procedure, it was originally one procedure which called all of the other procedures which are now the chain steps. I am being told that if any step fails than they dont want any of them performed

Comment: In that case I don’t see the point of the exercise. Capturing step timings perhaps? I’ve never used dbms_scheduler for anything complex but I’m pretty sure each job has to run in its own session and there is no setting to alter that.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Its not an exercise, it was the requirement I was given regardless of how accurate it was or not, its an all or nothing